# display EXACT time in as sections created

Tags: crystal-reports

how do I display exact time a report section is created?

Tried single formula and multiple formulas w/ NOW().  Tried Print Time in each section.

Such that if the report takes 30 minutes to run, report header might be 17:32:10 and report footer would be 18:03:49  ... and then each page header somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula and write below code:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Now()
```